# Bulk update product variations weight

Tags: views, commerce, actions

I've created a module for a custom VBO action.
The action can be selected in the view, and the function is executed, but `$request` is empty and the selected product variation IDs are not available.

```php
class VariationWeightSet extends ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase implements PluginFormInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('commerce_product_variation');

    if ($ids = explode('|', $request->query->get('ids'))) {
      $variations = $storage->loadMultiple($ids);
      $form_state->set('variations', array_values($variations));
      $variation = end($variations);
      $weight = $variation->getWeight()->toArray();
      $form['warning'] = [
        '#markup' => new TranslatableMarkup('<h1>Set new Weight for <span style="color:red">@count</span> variations</h1>', ['@count' => count($variations)]),
      ];
      $form['weight'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['container-inline']],
      ];
    }
    return $form;
  }

}
```

How can I get the selected product variation IDs?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't write code on demand. We can answer questions about code that doesn't work as expected, though, as long as the answer is Drupal-specific.

Comment: Yeah, I understand completely. I will start coding and try to update the question within a few days. Thanks.

Comment: The request is empty after submitting the VBO form.

Comment: The purpose of `buildConfigurationForm()` is building the form used to configure the action. The submitted values aren't taken from `\Drupal::request()`.

Comment: I understand. In case I want to add a #default_value?

Comment: You should first read [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/views-bulk-operations-vbo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139931/discussion-between-user3086053-and-apaderno).